# On a permutation module for GL(n,q)

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $G=GL(n,q)$ be the general linear group of degree $n$ over the $q$ element field.  Let $X$ be the set of full rank $n\times r$ matrices where $1\leq r\leq n$.  Then $G$ acts transitively on the left of $X$ by matrix multiplication and so we can form the permutation module $\mathbb CX$.

Let $T\colon \mathbb CX\to \mathbb CGL(r,q)$ be the linear map which takes a matrix $A$ from $X$ to the submatrix formed by its first $r$ rows if they are linearly independent and to $0$ otherwise.

I am interested in a direct, and preferably elementary, proof that $\ker T$ contains no non-zero $G$-invariant subspace of $\mathbb CX$.  Here elementary means avoiding too much specific information about the irreducible representations of $GL(n,q)$.

I believe that this is the case follows from results proved independently by Okninski and Putcha and by Kovacs on the semisimplicity of the algebra $\mathbb CM_n(\mathbb F_q)$, but both these sets of authors prove more general results and my hope is that the above result is easier to get at.

**Edit.**Kovacs result in fact implies that over any ground field outside of the defining characteristic there is no nontrivial $G$-invariant subspace of $\ker T$. Over a field of the defining characteristic the sum of all rank $r$ matrices spans  a $G$-invariant subspace in the kernel of $T$.